# UIAlertController translucency glitch/bug

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertcontroller

When iOS presents an alert, the translucency is constant. When my app presents one, the alert is white at first, only for half a second, then it becomes translucent. It's a small issue, but it looks messy and alerts should be consistent everywhere I think. Anyways here is the code:

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Invalid Credentials" message:@"Please try again." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [_username becomeFirstResponder];
}];
[alertVC addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I'm interested in people's opinions here as well. Is this just too small of an issue for anyone to be concerned about? It looks like this is just the way `UIAlertController` works (at least when developers use it). Regardless, it looks messy and I would consider it a bug (unless I'm doing something wrong) since it doesn't look the same as when iOS presents an alert, even though it should.

Comment: which version of iOS are you using.

Comment: same problem with 8.2, 8.3, and the simulator

Comment: I also noticed the same issue with UIAlertView

Comment: I think this might just be dog food

Comment: Are you launching this during animating some other UI?

Comment: dog food? I'm confused. I wonder if this happens for everyone, but no one notices/cares. I present alerts like this at about a dozen different times/scenarios in my app and they always appear white at first and then go translucent. There's definitely no animations happening.

Comment: By that I mean that developers external to Apple are deliberately given a lower quality api. Just as you would give dog food which you would not eat yourself to your dog.

Comment: Haha. It wouldn't surprise me in the least. I'm tempted to submit a bug report, but I'm pretty sure they'll just mark it "duplicate of (randomly generated number to unviewable (non-existant) "bug report") like they do with all my other bug reports.

Comment: Submit a bug report. Add a link to this Stackoverflow thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is part opinion, part educated guess, and part experience.

The `UIAlertController` has two main parts to it: the dark background and the message view. The dark background appears to be the very standard dark grey/black transparent view used for pop ups. The Message view looks to be using the same type of blur that's used for `UIToolbar` and `UINavigationController`.

The animation used for the transition for the `UIAlertController` is a fade in on the dark background and a combination of fade and contract on the message view. Fading isn't *that* difficult to do with a blurred view; iOS generally just uses a transparent view and the snaps to a blurred view above an `alpha` of `0.999`. That contracting animation though...that's where the magic is.

It's not just a frame resize, but the content of the message view actually changes size as well.

[image: Animation showing the UIAlertController message view size change.]

What's interesting about this is that instead of just resizing the frame of the message view and have the text fade in at a static size, someone at Apple decided to animate the text size changing as well to make it look like it's landing on the screen.

This label, button, and frame size changing combined with fading in a blur adds a fair amount of complexity to a rather simple view. So, instead of dealing with each separate issue, it looks like someone decided to use a snapshot of the view, animate the scale change and then "transition" to the desired look after the initial animation had completed.

As for why this isn't the case with messages directly in the OS...dog food.

Comment: It appears there is no solution so you get the bounty for explaining things. I'll send a bug report, even though every time I do one, it gets marked duplicate, and despite the problem being around for years, it never gets fixed. [self endRant];

Answer (score 0):

For me the same issue is caused by flag "Renders with edge antialiasing" set to YES in Info.plist file. 
It was once set to improve simulator tableview rendering, and who knew that it affecting system alerts rendering on device.